# Printing a certain number of properties from an object

Tags: javascript

Say I have an object like this:

```
   const recordCollection = {
2548: {
    albumTitle: 'Slippery When Wet',
    artist: 'Bon Jovi',
    tracks: ['Let It Rock', 'You Give Love a Bad Name']
  },
  2468: {
    albumTitle: '1999',
    artist: 'Prince',
    tracks: ['1999', 'Little Red Corvette']
  },
  1245: {
    artist: 'Robert Palmer',
    tracks: []
  },
  5439: {
    albumTitle: 'ABBA Gold'
  }
};
```

I know I can print a single property like this:

```
console.log (recordCollection[2548]['artist'];
```

And I wonder whether it is possible to do something like this:

```
console.log (recordCollection[2548]['artist', 'tracks'];
```

How would I  print both artist and tracks?

Comment: This is like you'd have red and green apple on a table, you can take the red apple and eat it, but there's no way to take the green apple?

Answer (score 0):

It should be: `recordCollection[2548]['artist']`

```js
const recordCollection = {
  2548: {
    albumTitle: 'Slippery When Wet',
    artist: 'Bon Jovi',
    tracks: ['Let It Rock', 'You Give Love a Bad Name']
  },
  2468: {
    albumTitle: '1999',
    artist: 'Prince',
    tracks: ['1999', 'Little Red Corvette']
  },
  1245: {
    artist: 'Robert Palmer',
    tracks: []
  },
  5439: {
    albumTitle: 'ABBA Gold'
  }
};
console.log(recordCollection[2548]['artist']);
```